# Java Array Advice

Tags: java, arrays, methods, runtime

I'm doing a practice problem and I'm stuck. The question is

"Given an array a of n numbers (say doubles), consider the problem of computing
the average of the first i numbers, for `i` ranging from `0` to `n-1`. That is, compute
the array b of length `n`, where
`b[i] = a[0] + a[1] ....+ a[i]/(i + 1)`
for `0 <= i < n`.
Write a Java program to solve this problem. Your program can generate its own
array, for example `a[i] = i + 1`. See how large an array you can process in less than
5 seconds. (For full credit it should be at least one million.)
Characterize the time complexity of your algorithm."

Here is my attempt at solving it:

```
public class largeArray{

public static void main(String[] args){

  double[] aa = new double[1000000];
  System.out.println(CalculateAvg(aa));




}
public static double CalculateAvg(double[] a){
  int i =0;
  double[] array = new double[i];
  a[i] = i + 1;

  for(int k=0; k<array.length; i++){
     double total = a[k]+a[k];
     double sum = ((total)/a[i]);
  }

 return a[i];
 }
}
```

Comment: You're not actually summing the values - you're declaring a new local variable on each iteration of the loop and doubling an existing value... and what's the `array` value for?

Comment: @JonSkeet Basically what I'm trying to do is create a program that has an array at an unfixed value and finding the average after 5 seconds has been up accordingly to the problem. I'm not quite sure how to initialize a starting value though to continue the run through. The array value was to test how many times after 5 seconds. It has no true meaning, just a test to see.

Comment: I don't see where finding the average *after 5 seconds* comes in. It just has to complete *before* 5 seconds. Hint: try declaring the total *outside* the loop, starting with zero, and summing the values. Then think about what an average is...

Comment: Difficult to give an answer here - you should take a step back and try to grasp the concepts of arrays and loops before you try to solve this assignment. E.g. you way want to say `double[] array = new double[a-lenghth];` to make a same-sized array as "a".

Answer (score 1):

If I got it correctly you have to generate an array B where B[i] is the average of the first i elements of the input array.

If this is the problem you can make a single loop that sums A[i] + B[i-1] and then does B[i-1]/i;

So it should be if A is the input array and B is the output:

```
B[0] = A[0]
for (int i = 1; i < n; i ++) {
    B[i] = A[i] + B[i-1];
    B[i-1] /= i;
}
B[n-1] /= n;
```

This is O(n) and it is the optimum in terms of complexity (because the problem is of computing the average of n number is T(n), ie it can not be resolved with complexity less than O(n)).

Also the constant is pretty low because you have just a few instructions per loop. This should keep you way bellow the 5 seconds.

Ahh I was forgetting, the generation of A is outside the 5 seconds analysis (it is the input).

Regards

Comment: Sorry I just forgot the division of the last element of the array B (the last average). I added it just now

Answer (score 0):

To start make a function to get the average of n given numbers (`maxNum`)

```
public int getAvgForNumbers(int maxNum){
int sum = 0;

for(int k=1; k<=maxNum; k++){
     sum = sum + k;
  }

return sum/maxNum;
}
```

Now use this function to populate your array by calling it starting from value 1 - `getAvgForNumbers(1)` till a number which you feel will get `getAvgForNumbers(x)`